# Proof that indicator function is random variable (Borel-measurable)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, solution-verification, borel-measures

I realize this highly trivial but it's precisely why I decided to ask it. Also my explanation doesn't quite match the correct one.

On a standard probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ we define a function
$$
X({\omega}) = 
\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1 & \text{ if }  A \in \mathcal{F}\\
0 & otherwise
\end{array}
$$
We need to find $\{\omega: X(\omega) = 1\} \Leftrightarrow X^{-1}(\{1 \}) = A$ and obviously $A \in \mathcal{F}$  by construction of $X$, so $X$ is a Borel-measurable random variable.

I'm sure my solution is solid, but it's a bit different from the correct one. Also it seems somewhat trivial.

Comment: There is something wrong with your displayed equation.  The right-hand side should depend on $\omega$ is some way, and doesn't seem to.  Maybe that's the discrepancy?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure. $X(\omega) = 1_A$ maybe, i.e. for some $A \in \mathcal{F}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the correct definition is

\begin{align*}
\chi_A(\omega):=\left\{\begin{array}{clc}
1 & \textrm{if}& \omega \in A\\
0 & \textrm{if} & \omega\in\Omega\setminus A
\end{array}\right.,
\end{align*}
where it is supposed $A\in\mathcal{F}$. Take any interval $(a, b]$ in $\mathbb R$. Then:
$$\chi_A^{-1}((a, b]))=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\Omega & \textrm{if}& 0\in (a, b]\ \textrm{and}\ 1\in (a, b]\\
\Omega\setminus A & \textrm{if} &0\in (a, b]\ \textrm{and}\ 1\not\in (a, b] \\
A & \textrm{if} &0\not\in (a, b]\ \textrm{and}\ 1\in (a, b]\\
\phi & \textrm{if} &\textrm{if}\ 0\not\in (a, b]\ \textrm{and}\ 1\not\in (a, b] 
\end{array}\right..$$

In any case, $\chi_A^{-1}((a, b])\in \mathcal{F}$. Since the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$ is generated by intervals of the kind $(a, b]$, $\chi_A$ is measurable.

Comment: So writing $\omega \in \mathcal{F}$ would be incorrect in this case?

Comment: Yes, ,the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ are some subsets of $\Omega$, not elements of $\Omega$.

Comment: In the textbook ('A first look at rigorous probability theory') the range of $X$ is simply defined as $1_A$, so I didn't conclude it actually means $\omega \in A$, I though it would be more like $\{x_i \} \in A$.

Comment: Also, for $X=0$, wouldn't it be correct to define it as $if \omega \notin A$?

Comment: sorry about it, but isn't it enough to show that either $X^{-1} =$  A or $X^{-1}({0})=\omega \in \Omega, \Omega \in 
\mathcal{F}$ by definition?

Comment: Note, however, that the proof is correct only if $A$ is a Borel set of $\Omega$ (which I hope is what you meant but "standard probability triple"). A counterexample would be a probability space $([0, 1], \mathcal{L}([0,1]), \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{L}([0, 1])$ is the set of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0, 1]$. So, there's a subset $A$ that's not a Borel set. Then, we can define that indicator function to be $1$ if $\omega \in A$. And then $X$ is not Borel measurable.

Comment: I am not sure that your answer is correct as the first row of the "if" of the inverse function contradict the very basic definition of a function. Indeed you can have two totally different interval i.e. $(a;b]$ and $(c;d]$ with $a<b<c<d$ that will match the same element $\Omega$ in the input set. So for one element in the input set corresponds 2 elements in the output set which cannot be true according to the definition of function.

Comment: @X0-user-0X Since $\chi_A : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, you cannot have the same element $\omega \in \Omega$ map into two disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.  (Additionally, while you say "inverse function" it's not an inverse function... as you wrote in your own answer, it's a preimage)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank for the precision it's exactly what i wanted to explain in my previous comment. And it seems me that the answer given above doesn't respect it.

Comment: @X0-user-0X I don't follow your point, then.  The only difference mathematically between your answer and PtF's original answer is that you've defined the indicator function $\Omega \to \{0,1\}$ while PtF defined it as $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.  Otherwise, an error in one is an error in the other.

Answer (score 0):

More generally you can prove that the indicator function is a borel function (and thus a r.v.). Here my prove but remember that I am just a student so I hope it is correct.

Let $(\Omega ; F )$ be a probabilisable space and $A \in F$ with $F$ a $\sigma$-algebra . The indicator function $\mathbb{1}_A:(\Omega;  F)\to (\{0,1\} ; \sigma(\{0,1\})$ is defined as follows:
$$
\mathbb{1}_A(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \omega \in A\\
0 & \text{if } \omega \notin A
\end{cases}
$$
We want to show that $\mathbb{1}_A$ is a Borel function, that means to prove that, the preimage of every element from the Borel set on $\{0,1\}$ (wrotte $\sigma(\{0,1\})$)under $\mathbb{1}_A$ is an element of $F$.

Let $B$ and element of the $\sigma$-algebra on$\{0,1\}$, in other words $B \in \sigma(\{0,1\}) $.
If $B=\emptyset$ so $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}(B)=\emptyset \in \Omega$
If $B=\{0\}$, then $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}(B)=\Omega \; without \; A \in F$ by definition of a $\sigma$-algebra the complement of $A$ belongs too to $F$.
If $B=\{1\}$, then $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}(B)=A $, which is also an element of $\Omega$ by definition.
Finally, if $B=\{0,1\}$, then $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}(B)=\Omega \in \sigma(\{0,1\})$.

Therefore, the preimage of every element of $\sigma(\{0,1\})$ under $\mathbb{1}_A$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $F$ on $\Omega$, and hence $\mathbb{1}_A$ is a Borel function.